# What kind of format this cloud be and how I can extackt key:value pairs from this text

Tags: c#, regex, text

I am tasked to convert an old Clarion (top-speed) app to MS-SQL database.
I have zero support for old app, I have to do all by myself.
I can't have (find) Clarion ODBC driver, I need just one shoot conversation of data.
When I open top-speed table whit TopSpeed editor I find sturcture of file like this

```
FILE,DRIVER('TOPSPEED'),NAME('C:\bIRA2013\BIRA_ARHIMED\ROBAGR.TPS')
ROBAGR:K_SIFGRU      KEY(+ROBAGR:SIFGRU),NOCASE,PRIMARY
ROBAGR:K_PRIHOD1_SIFGRU   KEY(+ROBAGR:PRIHOD1,+ROBAGR:SIFGRU),DUP,NOCASE
ROBAGR:K_PRIHOD2_SIFGRU   KEY(+ROBAGR:PRIHOD2,+ROBAGR:SIFGRU),DUP,NOCASE
ROBAGR:K_KUPAC_SIFGRU   KEY(+ROBAGR:KUPAC,+ROBAGR:SIFGRU),DUP,NOCASE
RECORD               RECORD
ROBAGR:SIFGRU          STRING(10)
ROBAGR:NAZIV           STRING(30)
ROBAGR:STOPA           DECIMAL(7,2)
ROBAGR:KOEF1           DECIMAL(7,4)
ROBAGR:KOEF2           DECIMAL(7,4)
ROBAGR:PRIHOD1         STRING(10)
ROBAGR:PRIHOD2         STRING(10)
ROBAGR:KUPAC           STRING(10)
ROBAGR:ID              STRING(2)
ROBAGR:D               LONG
                     END
                   END
```

To create new table at SQL I need to parse column,s names and types of this text.
Is this some standard tex format so I can search for C# library to parse this.
INI files has so many libraries  for C# and easily can be used, Does this format look to any "common" format so I can extract values of this ?
I need data stacked between record and firs end.
If I be pushed to parse this text manually, Should I go with regex or something other?
I want to parse this files by C#.

Comment: I don't know this format and so not answering the question, but it seems you could do this fairly easy with Regex knowing each new column title begins with "ROBAGR" and the data type is after the tab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a hand with regex, you might try this:

```
(?:RECORD|\G)\s*ROBAGR:(\S+)\s*(\S+)
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/sA6cP9)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/v3YEnb)